# What's a fast way to make Furikake from Katsobushi used in making dashi

Tags: japanese-cuisine, dashi

Making dashi uses about 10g of dried Katsobushi that ends up soaked.
Then soaked Katsobushi is then removed and tastes well. How can the soaked Katsobushi be reused?
The tricky part is that Katsobushi is preserved dried, after the dashi process it is rehydrated and hot. So Katsobushi cannot be stored for long and it is a waste to throw it away.
What are some key ingredients to make furikake and what is the basic process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no set recipe for furikake, but you will commonly find sesame seeds (both black or white), katsuobushi (bonito flakes), and seaweed.

For dashi leftovers, just cut the kombu/katsuobushi into small pieces and toast in a dry pan with some soy sauce/sugar/salt/MSG to taste until the mixture is dry. You can toast the sesame seeds separately or together with the dashi leftovers, then add nori (cut or crumbled into small pieces). Let cool, preferably on a tray to help it dry out more.

For quantities, [here is a recipe for reference](https://www.justonecookbook.com/homemade-furikake-rice-seasoning/).